# Find prime numbers in c#

Tags: c#, .net

before I start asking, I will tell what I did.
there was a problem, [problem 3](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=7), you can go to that link and see what it requires. 
To solve it, i just wrote a function to find if that number is prime or not. Simple.

But, problem 10 requires sum of all prime number under 2 million(2000000), I solve this by simply checking all numbers until 2m and see if its prime then add it to some variable.(if its prime)

However, doing that takes so much time. and with so much time i mean hours. lots of hours. so I dont think my answer was right :)

I googled the question before asking here, but I found no c#. closest one i can found was java and fortran, which i cant seem to realize the algorithm.

Here I am, asking this. how you could do this ? checking every number till 2m and notice it if its prime is not fast way.(also this questions supposed to be calculated under 1 minute(by problem i mean, not by you lol) afaik)

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read through the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You haven't posted any code, so there's no way of knowing what your competency level is for code. Also, it would help us as far as where to start improving your algorithm. One tip I can think of is to ***not check every number***. Once you've checked a number, you wont need to check multiples. Half of the numbers `< 2,000,000` are multiples of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly modified version of Ben Voigt:

```
    public static void FirstPrime(int limit)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        bool[] composite = new bool[limit];
        long sum = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 3; i < limit; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 1)
            {
                if (!composite[i])
                {
                    ++count;
                    sum += i;
                    for (int j = i; j < limit; j += 2 * i)
                        composite[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        count++;
        sum += 2;
        Console.WriteLine("There are " + count + " prime numbers less than " + limit + " totalling " + sum);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}",sw.Elapsed);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

When test with Limit = 20,000,000, the original version costs 1,23s, and this version cost 0,7259s

When test with Limit = 50,000,000, the original version costs 3,34s, and this version cost 1,988s

Generally, this version is about 1.6 times faster :)

Comment: If you're so concerned with efficiency, wouldn't it be better to use i += 2 rather than i++ and skip the "if ((i % 2) == 1)" check?

Comment: great catch :), reduced runtime about 8% :)

Comment: I don't know where you're getting these numbers, but it's only 0.1 seconds for 50,000,000 iterations: http://ideone.com/5rF2O  Skipping the odd numbers saves just a tiny bit: http://ideone.com/5f0m1

Comment: I benchmarked on my machine, and Limit = 50,000,000 , not 5,000,000 :)

Comment: @Vim... ack!  I set it to 50000000, got a runtime error, set it back to 2000000 to debug, then forgot a zero when increasing it again.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: he's obviously getting those numbers from a different computer than the one you're using.

Comment: Anyway, you should never use `Console.WriteLine` inside the timed section.

Comment: On my computer, running with limit = 2,000,000,000, the difference between hitting all numbers and skipping even numbers is 26.753 seconds vs 25.275 ... or about 6%.  I wonder if a garbage collection gets charged to the second and third versions in your testing?

Comment: My original post was without the third version, but I can't get to run with limit = 2,000,000,000, OutOfMemoryException was thrown. When tried with 500,000,000, the times were 22s and 38s :). My machine is Q6700/4GB of RAM

Comment: @Vimvq: Mine is Core i5/8GB, so that may explain why I can get a larger array.  oh!  I just noticed you also doubled the stride of j.  More testing...

Comment: Crap, I think I've found an optimizer bug.  On the plus side, I can reproduce your 40% time reduction by doubling the stride on `j`.  The *unoptimized* version with `j += i*2` is 40% faster than the *optimized* version without.  The *optimized* version with, gives wrong results.

Comment: can you post your configuration? This would be very interesting. I'm using VS2010 premium, will try with release mode :). The time is slightly better, 18.65s and 31.67s, but the result is correct :)

Comment: @Vimvq: Have a look at the bug report I linked in my answer.  `csc /o-` gives correct results, as does `csc /o+ /checked`.  But `csc /o+` alone does not, apparently due to an internal integer overflow in the JIT compiler.

Comment: @Vimvq1987 I just remembered that you can also define your loop as `for (int j = i * i; j < limit; j += 2 * i)` because any composite between i and i * i must have an already-processed prime as one of its factors, so it has already been marked.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of checking each number individually for primality, you could (should) use a sieve.

Maybe you can even figure out the sum of all numbers the sieve removes at once...

Straightforward solution hidden below:

> http://ideone.com/55j4F

A <strike>slightly</strike> considerably faster version (thanks to [@Vimvq1987](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246822/project-euler-problem-10-in-c/6247593#6247593)):

> http://ideone.com/bxq2h

And an associated .NET 4.0 bug, I believe: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/674232/jit-optimizer-error-when-loop-controlling-variable-approaches-int-maxvalue

Comment: I think this is probably the best bet. It's been a while, but I remember The Seive of Eratosthenes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) being fairly straightforward to implement. There might be more efficient methods, but then there's the tradeoff between ease of implementation and efficiency.

Comment: @Thomas: That was my intent.  Actually, I just implemented the Sieve of Eratosthenes to see, it runs in 50 milliseconds on ideone.

Answer (score 3):

See [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for details on a 'fast' prime number search algorithm. The wikipedia entry even points to [a C# implementation](http://paratechnical.blogspot.com/2011/01/c-implementation-of-parallel-sieve-of.html). Another option might be to research any mathematical properties of sums of prime numbers.